# Jsoup element is empty when selecting by class

Tags: java, html, jsoup

The html i am parsing is like this:

```
<article id="1234" class="bg-post ">
....
</article>
```

When I try parsing it using jsoup I am getting an empty string

```
Elements e = doc.select("article[class=bg-post ]");
```

OR using

```
Elements e = doc.getElementsByClass("bg-post ");
```

The size of `e` is 0 and `e.toString()` is empty.

Does it have something to do with the **space** at the end of the class name, how do I resolve this issue.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Also tried searching without the space

```
Elements e = doc.select("article[class=bg-post]");
```

Still the same problem.

Comment: You have trailing " ]".. Should it be just "bg-post"?

Comment: a typo, edited the question

Comment: Your code works fine for me with jsoup 1.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug affecting `JSoup` versions before `1.8.2`

You cannot simply select elements by attributes' value if they are not correctly space-normalized.

If you really have to stick to some old `JSoup` version, you can workaround it in this less-performant way:

```
document.select(".bg-post").select("article")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
Elements e = doc.select("article[class=bg-post ]");
```

works fine!

Here is my code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/index.html").get();
Elements select = document.select("article[class=bg-post ]");
```

Result:
[image: Result]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<article id="1234" class="bg-post ">
  <div>test1</div>
  <div>test2</div>
  <div>test3</div>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

and dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.3</version>
</dependency>
```